# ORDER BY with two columns (only one column has a value)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have created a simple calendar, on the one hand with timepoints and on the other hand with timeperiods.

**MySQL table (a block with much 0's means: no real value here because it's a timepoint and not a period of time)**

```
+-------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| title | timepoint1 | timepoint2 | timeperiod1 | timeperiod2 |
+-------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| ABC   | 2015-07-12 | 12:30:00   | 0000-00-00  | 0000-00-00  |
| UPS   | 2015-07-12 | 15:00:00   | 0000-00-00  | 0000-00-00  |
| DEF   | 2015-07-30 | 08:00:00   | 0000-00-00  | 0000-00-00  |
| HIJ   | 0000-00-00 | 00:00:00   | 2015-07-16  | 2015-07-31  |
| KLM   | 0000-00-00 | 00:00:00   | 2015-08-21  | 2015-08-25  |
+-------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**I want an output like this**

```
+-------+--------------------------+
| title | when?                    |
+-------+--------------------------+
| ABC   | 2015-07-12   12:30       |
| UPS   | 2015-07-12   15:00       |
| HIJ   | 2015-07-16 to 2015-07-31 |
| DEF   | 2015-07-30    8:00       |
| KLM   | 2015-08-21 to 2015-08-25 |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

As you can see I want to order all titles by their starting time (whether it's a timepoint or a period of time), maybe including the time like 12 o'clock etc.

But how should I write the query, especially the ORDER BY part. And how can I add a WHERE clause which only selects meetings which are in this or in the following month?

Comment: You should really have put the date and time in the same column under a datetime data type. Then you have two of those, one for start and one for end. If this just represents a single point in time then start == end. If this represents a whole single day then start is `00:00:00.000` that day and end is `23:59:59.999` that day. Else you end up with odd cases like this where you have to use a `case/when` or `greatest` statement.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know exactly why I did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatinate the two fields and order by that.

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(`timepoint1`,' ',`timepoint2`) ASC
```

Seeing that some fields might be empty, then you'd use IF statements, like:

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(IF(`timepoint1`!='0000-00-00',`timepoint1`,`timeperioid1`),' ',`timepoint2`) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title
, IF(timepoint1 = '0000-00-00'
   , CONCAT(timeperiod1, " to ", timeperiod2)
   , CONCAT(timepoint1, ' ', timepoint2)
) AS `when?`
FROM the_table
ORDER BY GREATEST(timepoint1, timeperiod1), timepoint2, timeperiod2
;
```

That said, why not just have two DATETIME or TIMESTAMP fields (a "from" and a "to")? "Periods" would use the '00:00:00' time, or "points" would have "from" and "to" equal to each other, or there could be an additional "type" field of some sort. The first comment made also shows a good way of covering a single day "period".